# Onedrive SharePoint Sync read only files

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, onedrive-for-business, sync

So I'm trying to sync my SharePoint libraries locally

Originally, when I wanted to do that, I found out that any field/column having the "required" parameter would cause the local sync to lock the files as read only on the computer and prevent any copy / pasting of files into that local folder.

Once the required fields were changed to "optional" the files were available as read/write on my computer.

We wanted to start using the **Content Type Hub** provisioned with SharePoint Online.

I copied my main site template with it's custom fields and content types onto our **Content Type Hub** using provisioning commands.

I now have that strange problem.  The Content Type Hub seems to work fine, other sites are able to pull the custom columns and content types.  I can sync the libraries of those sites to my local computer and everything is fine.

But my main site now locks the synched libraries back to read only.

I have not been able to identify any differences between the main sites fields and content types and the Hub.  There should be no difference since one is a copy of the other.

I've read something about versioning maybe creating some issues, but didn't find much about it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

Some Columns were set as required again.  Need to go in each library, changed the Library Setting **Advance settings** 
Then go into "Allow management of content types?" and change it to **No**

Go back to the Settings and look for columns that has a checkmark in the Required column
[image]

Change the column settings to Required - No

Then re-enable the Advance Settings, "Allow Management of content 
types?" Yes

My only question is, is there a way to fix this for all libraries without having to go in each one.